# Casting buffers as structures

Tags: c++

I'm doing this as a learning exercise. The C++ book I'm studying from casts a buffer as a structure for easy manipulation and streaming. Everything seems fine until I try using an array (body) and look at the binary data in the buffer after assigning values. It doesn't match what I expect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <netinet/in.h>

using namespace std;

struct dataStruct
{
    uint32_t header;
    uint32_t *body;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size, streamSize;

    // 4 bytes per size + 4 bytes for header
    size = 1;
    streamSize = (size * 4) + 4;

    // Create a stream of bytes of appropriate size
    uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[streamSize];

    // Cast stream as structure
    dataStruct *sStream = (dataStruct *)buffer;

    // Populate structure with nice 101010... binary patterns
    sStream->header = 2863311530;
    sStream->body = new uint32_t[1];
    sStream->body[0] = 2863311530;
    cout << "Struct: " << sStream->header << ", " << sStream->body[0] << endl;

    // Look at raw data in stream
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)
    {
        std::bitset<8> x(buffer[i]);
        cout << "[" << i << "]->" << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Struct: 2863311530, 2863311530
[0]->10101010
[1]->10101010
[2]->10101010
[3]->10101010
[4]->00000000
[5]->00000000
[6]->00000000
[7]->00000000
```

Why is index 4-7 not the same as 0-3?  Both sStream->header and sStream->body contain the same values. They are mapped to the buffer. Is this because body is an array? If so how would I manipulate the stream for this to work when using an array?

Thanks

Comment: One issue is that `size` is uninitialized (probably 0 in your case, bun in any case undefined behaviour) - hence `buffer` points to a memory area of unknown size

Comment: `Both sStream->header and sStream->body contain the same values` No, the body **points to** 10101010... `sizeof(buffer)` is 8 since buffer is a pointer; you don't get the size of the contents. Hence you print 8 bytes, the first 4 are an integer and the next 4 are *part of* the mentioned body pointer. Of this pointer, the first four bytes seem to be zero, you neither see the full pointer (since you display only 4 bytes of it) nor do you see the contents of the pointer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using uninitialized varieable `size` in:

```
streamSize = (size * 4) + 4;
```

Everything after that depends on `streamSize` is suspect and is a cause for undefined behavior.

**Update**

Even after `size` is initialized to `1`, there are problems. Let's me walk through the code and how it affects the memory you have allocated.

After you execute the line:

```
uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[streamSize];
```

you have `buffer` pointing to memory like this:

```
buffer
|
v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

After you have executed the line:

```
dataStruct *sStream = (dataStruct *)buffer;
```

you have `sStream` pointing to the same memory like:

```
sStream
|
v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If your compiler does not add any padding to the members of `dataStruct` (the best case scenario), you'll have:

```
sStream.header  sStream.body
|               |
v               v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If your compiler adds padding to `dataStream.header`, `sStream.body` will point to something different. Worst case scenario: You have a 64-bit compiler. It adds 32 bits of padding to `dataStream.header`. In that case, you will have:

```
sStream.header                  sStream.body
|                               |
v                               v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Then, you will end up using unathorized memory when you try to assign anything to `sStream.body`, like:

```
sStream->body = new uint32_t[1];
```

Best case scenario, you have 32 bit compiler and there is no padding added to `dataStream.header`. Looks like you have a 64-bit compiler. Even if you compiler does not add any padding to `dataStream.header`, you are still looking at a memory overrun problem if `sizeof(void*)` is 64 bits, which I think you do.

Let's take the best case scenario of a 32 bit compiler that doesn't add any padding and the member of `sStream` point to the allocated memory like:

```
sStream.header  sStream.body
|               |
v               v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

After you execute the line:

```
sStream->header = 2863311530;
```

the memory looks like:

```
sStream.header  sStream.body
|               |
v               v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2863311530    |               |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

After you execute the line:

```
sStream->body = new uint32_t[1];
```

the memory looks like:

```
sStream.header  sStream.body
|               |
v               v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2863311530    |  SomeMemory   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

SomeMemory
|
v
+---+---+---+---+
|               |
+---+---+---+---+
```

After you execute the line:

```
sStream->body[0] = 2863311530;
```

`SomeMemory` gets populated and looks like:

```
SomeMemory
|
v
+---+---+---+---+
| 2863311530    |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I think you were surprised to see that the memory pointed to by `buffer` does not look like:

```
buffer
|
v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2863311530    | 2863311530    |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I hope it makes sense now why it does not.

Comment: The missing value of size was a typo. I just added it.

Comment: Wow, great answer. This really helps. I know I can always use a std::vector but wanted to get a better understanding and manually manipulate the data before I jumped into a safe container class. Thank you so much!